# Android studio virtual device not loading

Tags: java, android

I have 4GB of memory ram, the android studio virtual device is showing "ANDROID", so the loading is infinite, it doesn't end, I've waited too long, what can be the problem? no matter what application I use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use Genymotion? It's hundreds of times better than regular virtual device. Here you have a post to "how to" use it: http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2013/11/22/android-studio-plus-genymotion-emulator/

Remember to use a real phone to make some tries but Genymotion it's almost the same thing.

Hardware requisites are:

> Hardware
>
> Genymotion implies that you have the following hardware on your
>   computer: OpenGL 2.0 capable video card, with an up-to-date driver;
>   VT-x or AMD-V capable CPU, enabled in BIOS settings; RAM memory: at
>   least 2GB; Screen resolution greater than 1024 x 768 pixels; Free
>   space on hard disk: at least 100MB.

UPDATE: Bear in mind this response it's old and now Genymotion is not longer free. Using x86 emulator nowadays it's a great solution to work with.

Comment: I don't think "Abandon the software suite that you're using for another (paid) product" is a viable answer to his question. For example, I am also in his shoes, and I am not in a purchasing position at my company.

Comment: @BryanRayner This question was 2 years ago and Genymotion was free back then. Now it has a trial period. Since then, the Android Emulator x86 is the best option with the official software.