# Android Studio Emulator not work

Tags: android, emulation

I downloaded Android Studio 1.32 and installed it, downloaded also all APIs. I tried to make a new project and get the emulator working. I made an empty blank project which has "Hello World" text already in it.

If I try to make a new device Tools-AVD-Manager it lets me make a new device.
Then I click Tools-Android-Android Device Monitor. It shows nothing and I have tried to made some..

When I try to run the project and it gives "Create Android Virtual Device" (which gives only few details about it). This produces error: `unable to find emulatorsnapshots.img.`

I tried  to test this before using Eclipse which worked somehow but always there were emulator errors. So I was thinking Android Studio will fix them... But seems that is not working, even downloading whole 4gb packet...

Answer (score 1):

Check my response to a similar issue: [Android Studio Virtual Device not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298046/android-studio-virtual-device-not-loading/32298849#32298849)

Genymotion it's a better solution when that kind of issues happen and it can be easily use it with Android Studio.